# Copy or print chat window text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chat

I keep encountering in increasing frequency these chat interfaces with disabled right-click, disabled marking (when I try to mark in order to copy, the mark usually doesn't stick) and even when I do manage to mark the text CTRL-C doesn't work.

I can save the HTML and then sift through it to get the chat contents or open it in IE and save as text file (as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/705230/how-can-i-copy-text-from-a-web-page-where-it-been-has-disabled)) but it's long and tedious to do that every time I want to save a chat for record.

Screenshot or printing the page to PDF doesn't help because it only saves a small part of the conversation.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (a script / utility / extension would also be acceptable, though I would prefer if it wasn't an extension as they hog memory).

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Chrome extension that can help you: RightToCopy

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/righttocopy/plmcimdddlobkphnofejmeidjblideca

In Chrome Store, it says:

> Enable right click, saving images, selecting/highlighting text, and
>   copying text on pages that have disabled these features.

Comment: Damn, tried it and it doesn't do the job :(

Comment: You can try using Firefox, it probably has a similar plugin that may work in your case.

You can also try disabling/modifying the Javascript that blocks the Copy/Paste. See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thanks, but using Firefox is not an option in this case since if I have to switch to Firefox every time I use one of these chats I might as well use one of the solutions I listed (it's the same amount of work for me). The same for disabling / modifying the JavaScript...

Comment: @traveh What version of [RightToCopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plmcimdddlobkphnofejmeidjblideca) were you using? Version 8.0 worked on every site I visited.

Comment: @Kootling no idea... it was the latest at the time.

Comment: Try reinstalling the extension or updating it and see if it works for you.